# FirebaseMessagingService #onMessageReceived is not being called

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

Firebase Server sends notification, I get it, but my MyFirebaseMessagingService's onMessageReceived is not being called.

This is MyFirebaseMessagingService:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static String id;
    private static PSTrip trip;

    public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage message) {
        Log.i("", "MyFirebaseMessagingService onMessageReceived");
        final Map data = message.getData();
        FcmService.triggerSmoochNotification(data, this);
        final Map bundle = data;
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i("", "GLOBAL intances  before GCM:" + Realm.getGlobalInstanceCount(PSApplicationClass.Config));
                final Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(PSApplicationClass.Config);
                try {
                    final RealmResults < PSTrip > completed = realm.where(PSTrip.class).equalTo("status", "active").findAll();
                    if (completed != null && completed.size() > 0) {
                        id = new String(completed.get(0).getId());
                        trip = new PSTrip(completed.get(0));
                        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                            @Override
                            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                                completed.deleteAllFromRealm();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    generateNotificationStandard(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, data.get("title"), message, null, null, false, false);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Utils.appendLog("GCMIntentService onMessageReceived error: " + e.getMessage(), "E", Constants.PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS);
                }
                realm.close();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am using this version of firebase:

> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'

And I have my FirebaseMessagingService declared in my AndroidManifest like this:

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Somehow my notifications are shown, but my method is not being called. How can I make it so my messages are received and handled through this?

Also: the server uses this to send the data. Might this be the issue? https://github.com/jazzband/django-push-notifications

## EDIT:

Also tried:

```
 <service android:name="nl.hgrams.passenger.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

as in to give the full path. but still nothing.

Comment: which device you used to test notification?

Comment: when you receiving your notification where your application is location either foreground or bakground

Comment: I use a Nexus 5, LeEco LePro2 and a Huawei Mate 10 Pro. PS: I do get the notification, either if the app is in background, or foreground. BUT I get a default notification. My FirebaseMessagingService is not called

Comment: what type of message send by fcm.i am using data message so it will works.are you using data message or notification message? if you use notification message our firebase sdk handle process and show notification in system tray automatically

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive refer this too

Comment: I asked the server guy to check, cause he uses this library: firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive 
I assume the issue is he is sending notification message, and that is why it goes dirrectly to the tray?
I am now looking into the link you have sent me, and will have an update

Comment: Also, I tried and Smooch notifications do call the onMessageReceived function. Referring to this: https://smooch.io/

Comment: @RevathiManoharan you are right, it was the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server part of the app was trying to send as Notification Message. This is what was causing the issue, and after I figured this out, I talked with the backend guy, in order to change the code to use Data Message, and now it works